# Finding all circular prime numbers below a a given number in python

Tags: python, primes, circular-dependency

I needed to write a code which generates all the circular prime numbers below any given number. There are some flaws in my code, it does not provide all the all the circular prime numbers just a few of them. It will only show all the circular prime numbers if theyre all below my given number. 
for example, if upper = 200 it will not show the circular prime number 197. The other rotations are 971 and 719. However, if upper = 1000 it will show all 3 circular prime numbers. 
I dont know if its a logical or code error but any and all help is appreciated.

```
from collections import deque
def gen_primes(upper):

    D = {}
    q = 2
    while q <= upper:
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]       
        q += 1 

def circular_primes(upper):
    circular = []

    primes = list(gen_primes(upper-1))

    for prime in primes:
        string = str(prime)
        digits = deque(string)

        for rotation in range(1, len(string)):
            digits.rotate(1)

            if int("".join(digits)) not in primes:
                break
        else:
            circular.append(prime)

    return circular
print(circular_primes(150))
```

Comment: Your list of primes only contains numbers up to "upper". But in your first example 200 < 971. Therefore 971 is not listed as prime. For numbers larger than "upper" you need a separate prime check.

Comment: I understand why 971 isnt included, but 197 also isnt but it is less than 200?

Comment: Because the prime is only seen as circular if all rotations are listed as prime and the rotations >200 are not listed in "primes".

Comment: aahh i see thank you so much.

Comment: Any multi-digit prime that contains the digits 0, 2, 4, 5, 6 or 8 cannot be prime because at least one rotation will end in that digit and so be composite.  Both 2 and 5 are single digit primes, but cannot appear in a multi-digit circular prime.

Answer (score 0):

**Code fix**

You're not creating primes that cover all the possible rotations.

Add function that computes the smallest number larger than n and all it's rotations.

```
def next_largest(n):
  " For number n, returns number smallest number larger than all rotation of n "
  k = len(str(n))

  return 10**k
```

**Refactored Code**

```
from collections import deque
def gen_primes(upper):

    D = {}
    q = 2
    while q <= upper:
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]       
        q += 1 

def next_largest(n):
   " For number n, returns number smallest number larger than all rotation of n "
  k = len(str(n))

  return 10**k

def circular_primes(upper):
    circular = []

    print(next_largest(upper))
    primes = list(gen_primes(next_largest(upper)))  # code mod

    for prime in primes:
        string = str(prime)
        digits = deque(string)

        for rotation in range(1, len(string)):
            digits.rotate(1)

            if int("".join(digits)) not in primes:
                break
        else:
            circular.append(prime)

    return circular
```

**Test**

```
print(circular_primes(200))
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, 97, 113, 131, 197, 199, 311, 337, 373, 719, 733, 919, 971, 991]
```